# Fixing code for a combinatorics problem

Tags: list-manipulation, combinatorics, sets

The problem I am solving is:

> Determine all possible values of positive integer $n$, such that there are $n$ different $3$-element subsets $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ of the set $\{1,2,...,n\}$, with $|A_i \cap A_j| \not= 1$ for all $i \not= j$.

I already know that every $n=4k$ satisfies the conditions. I am verifying this with the following code:

```
n = 4;
sets = Subsets[Range[n], {3}]
AllTrue[Length /@ Intersection @@@ Subsets[sets, {2}], # != 1 &]
```

However, when I set $n = 8$, the result is `False`, which is incorrect.

How can I fix my code?

Comment: I'm not following.  There are 56 different 3-element subsets when $n=8$.  Do you mean that one can find a set of 8 of those 56 that satisfy your restriction?  Or am I missing something?

Comment: there are more than `n` different 3-element subsets that satisify this condition for any integer n>3. In fact (kind of unrelated but interesting), there is a closed form for the number of 3-element subsets satisfying your condition:

$\frac{1}{72} (-3 + n) (-2 + n) (-1 + n) n (38 + (-9 +n) n)$

Comment: Your code tests every pairwise intersection of  all the 3 element subsets of 8 element set. This is not exactly what you want.  Restating your problem, there exists a collection of n different subsets agreeing with condition. You need to find them. A strategy is to partition your 4k set into k 4 element sets and then  3 subset each 4 element set. The 4 element will always satisfy your conditions: {1,2,3}, {1,2,4}, {2,3,4}, {1,3,4}: each intersection length 2.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See my comment.

Here is a way to construct sets of size 4 k fulfilling requirement.

```
fun[n_? (Mod[#, 4] == 0 &) ] : = Module  [ {p = Partition [Range [n], 4]},Join @@ (Subsets [#, {3}] & /@ p) ]
```

Testing

```
fun[8]
```

[image]

Now testing that is it satisfies condition:

```
test[u_]:=AllTrue[Intersection @@@Subsets[u, {2}], Length[#] != 1 &] 


test[fun [8]]
```

gives True, as does:

```
test[fun [12]]
```

I apologize for the formatting. I don’t have access to computer. This was done from phone and Wolfram cloud. Of course, I apologize for any errors or misunderstanding.